# How to unset fieldset in hook_form_alter?

Tags: 7, forms

I want to unset a **fieldset** programmatically which is available in the content type. I tried to unset like this in `hook_form_alter`,

```
 unset($form['field_first_deposit']);
```

But it doesn't work, where as hiding individual fields works in the same format. I tried hide() too , but still it doesn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mentioned solution `['#access'] = false` will be a possible solution, but if it's not working you may try:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $form['#after_build'][] = 'YOUR_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_after_build';

}

/**Replace MACHINE_NAME with your fieldset group machine name.**/

function YOUR_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_after_build(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // Hide the B2B group.
  field_group_hide_field_groups($form, array('group_MACHINE_NAME'));

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Its still showing the fieldset after adding the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter and _after_build() also.

Comment: Is the FORM ID correct may be its not working because of the form id.

Comment: you can use GET FORM ID module to check that

Comment: I haven't used the recent version of field groups module and field_group_hide_field_groups() is not available in that version. Now updated the field groups version and seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal form API has the [`#access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#access) element for fields that toggles visibility. If you need hide a fieldset, you'll need to do both.

```
$form['field_first_deposit']['#access'] = false;
hide($form['field_first_deposit']);
```

Comment: I tried that option also and it doesn't seems to be working.Its showing the fieldset.

Comment: It looks like you have to do both `hide()` & `#access`.

Comment: Having both also still it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code :

```
$form['field_first_deposit']['#access'] = '0';
```

It will hide the field

Answer (score 0):

For **Drupal 8/9** this works

```
$form['field_first_deposit']['#access'] = false;
```