# How do I disable a fieldset?

Tags: 8, forms

I read [How to unset fieldset in hook_form_alter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159859/how-to-unset-fieldset-in-hook-form-alter) to disable fieldsets in an `hook_form_alter()` implementation, but it didn't work.

I tried using the following code, but neither of them worked.

```
// First try.
foreach ($form['#fieldgroups']['group_employment']->children as $form_element_id) {
  $form[$form_element_id]['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
}
```

```
// Second try
foreach ($form['#fieldgroups']['group_employment']->children as $form_element_id) {
  $form[$form_element_id]['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
}
```

How can I disable fieldsets?

Comment: you work with field_group module ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access directly to `#fieldgroups` in `form_alter` you should add `pre_render` function like the following:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    $form['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_form_pre_render';
  }
}

/**
 * @param $form
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function mymodule_form_pre_render($form) {
  foreach ($form['#fieldgroups']['group_employment']->children as $form_element_id) {
    $form[$form_element_id]['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
  return $form;
}
```

**Edit** :
if you want to just disable the fields change the `pre_render` function by:

```
function mymodule_form_pre_render($form) {
  foreach ($form['#fieldgroups']['group_employment']->children as $form_element_id) {
    if (isset($form[$form_element_id])) {
      //- For entity reference fields
      if (isset($form[$form_element_id]['widget'][0]['target_id'])) {
        $form[$form_element_id]['widget'][0]['target_id']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
      }
      //- For normal input form
      if (isset($form[$form_element_id]['widget'][0]['value'])) {
        $form[$form_element_id]['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
      }
    }
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: How can I disable the fieldgroup? I can unset them successfully but how can I set the disable attribute?

Comment: i edited my answer check it out.